# How to include schematic page name in OrCAD BOM

Tags: orcad

I am generating BOM in OrCAD. How can I include a part's schematic page name in the Bill of Materials csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly. You could generate the xref file and use that plus a one-part-per-line BOM and merge them in Perl or Excel.

Comment: Brian, Can you explain these step by step.How to generate xref file.

Answer (score 1):

Open a schematic page.
Right click to set the Selection Filter to select only "Parts".
Select all the parts on the page.
Right click to Edit Properties.
Click on "New Property", name it "Page" and enter the page name as the value.
Do this for all pages.
Create the Bill of Materials, adding the "Page" tag to the Header and Combined Property String, following the syntax of the other tags.